# Density of $C^{\infty}(I) \cap W^{1,\infty}(I)$ in $W^{1,\infty}(I)$

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

I was inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838458/on-the-density-of-mathcalc-infty-omega-cap-w1-infty-omega-in-w?rq=1) and Meyers-Serrin theorem to prove that there exists a function $u \in W^{1,\infty}(I) $ such that there are no functions $u_m \in C^{\infty}(I) \cap W^{1,\infty}(I)$ with $u_m \to u$ in $W^{1,\infty}(I)$.

Generally speaking, I'm trying to prove that $C^{\infty}(I) \cap W^{1,\infty}(I)$ is not dense in $W^{1,\infty}(I)$. This leads me into more difficulties than I supposed. Hints?

Moreover, what is the closure of $C^{\infty}(I) \cap W^{1,\infty}(I)$ wrt $W^{1,\infty}(I)$-norm?

Here $I$ is only an open interval of the real line. I would try to generalize this fact by myself.

Comment: The closure of $C^\infty$ in $W^{1,\infty}$ is $C^1$, just like the closure of $C^\infty$ in $L^\infty$ is $C^0$.

Comment: So if $\Vert u_m - u \Vert \to 0$ then $u \in C^1$. This sounds great. If I want to find a function which lies in $W^{1,\infty}$ but not in that intersection, can I use $\vert x \vert$ in $I = (-a,a)$?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I'll turn my comment into an answer in a short while.

Comment: But if $\Vert u_m \to u \Vert$ then $u \in C^1$ but this only means that $C^1$ contains the closure. What about the viceversa? i.e. if $u \in C^1$ there exist functions $u_m$ that approximate $u$?

Comment: Yes, by a standard smoothing argument.

Comment: Can you develop your last statement? What do you mean?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

Comment: So if $u \in C^1$ then I can mollify it and I get $u_{\epsilon}$. Thus, if $u$ has compact support, then $u_{\epsilon} \to u$ uniformly and this is good, but what about for general $u$?

Comment: Extend $u$ continuously outside the interval and mollify.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t understand. Take for example u $\in C^1(1,\infty)$ with $u(\infty) \neq 0$. How can you conclude that $u_{\epsilon}$ converges to $u$?

Comment: The case of unbounded domains is more complicated.

Comment: No ideas. I’m exhausted :(